# 0/1 dB normalization using clamp function

Tags: audio, amplitude, normalization

I would like to perform dB normalization on audio data to make less loud sound louder and to make unusually loud sound less loud, before feeding them into neural networks.

I came across this function:

$$S':= \frac{S-db_{ref}-db_{min}}{-db_{min}}  $$

where $db_{ref}=20$ and $db_{min}=-100$.

The clamp function is:
If $s'<0$ or $>1$, $s=0$ or $1$. If $s'$ is in $[0,1]$, $s'=s'$.

I am confused about why dividing $S-db_{ref}-db_{min}$ by ${-db_{min}}$ in the transformation? What is the intuition or how does it normalize the amplitude?

(The idea of clamping anything below $0$ or $1$ to $0$ and $1$ is clear to me.)

As well, what is $db_{ref}$ and why set it to $20$? Why setting $db_{min}$ to $-100$?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know what a formula does, it's always a good idea to just plot it.

[image]

This is a simple linear mapping, i.e.

$$S' = \frac{S-dB_{ref}}{-dB_{min}}+1$$

When $S = dB_{ref}$ than $S' = 1$ and the slope is $-dB_{min}$, i.e. 100 dB.  S' becomes 2 if S is 100dB above $dB_{ref}$ and it becomes 0 if it's 100dB below $dB_{ref}$.

> As well, what is dbref and why set it to 20? Why setting dbmin to −100?

$dB_{ref}$  is what  you want the level to be and $dB_{min}$ is the level at which you just shut it off. The absolute values depend on how the data is calibrated and the requirements of your application.

> I came across this function:

I suggest looking elsewhere. What you need is normal audio compressor that's adjusted to specifics of your data and specifically to the noise floor. You want to make sure you pick time constants and slopes that preserve the features you want to neural network to learn while decreasing dynamic range as much as possible.

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed answer!!